# Admob ads not showing. Test ads work fine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

My test ad works fine, but when I replace the ad unit id with my real one, nothing pop ups. I created the ad unit ID 3 days ago. I made sure to double check the ad unit id.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

```
interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "MY AD UNIT ID")
let request = GADRequest()
interstitial.load(request)
return interstitial
```

Comment: Are you testing on a simulator?  Does the console show anything after this is called? let request = GADRequest()

Comment: I am testing on both the simulator and my real device. The test ad works fine on both. I replace the id, and my other function still prints “There is an ad” but nothing appears unlike the test ad. @AlexBailey

Comment: if test ad work fine on both then  is your ads ID is approved  ?

Comment: Have you enabled test devices.https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices